# .Net CORE Web API no-cache but still happens

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Using .Net Core and visual studio 2015.

I have a Web API create in .net core, Recently in testing i realized my results are being cached (or atleast appear to be). So i implimented a response cache and set location to none:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class NopProductController : Controller
{
    private INopProductService _nopProductService { get; set; }
    public NopProductController(INopProductService nopProductService)
    {
        _nopProductService = nopProductService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 60, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
    public IActionResult GetChangedProducts()
    {
        return Ok(_nopProductService.GetChanged());
    }
}
```

When i checked Postman and checked the headers, i found:

> Cache-Control →no-cache,max-age=60 
>   Pragma →no-cache

which looks correct i beleive. However when i edit data in my Sql Server 2012 DB on the table in question (i change 1 cell value) then refresh the request, the change isnt there.

As you can see it appears caching is turned off.  So why would no change happen, only when i reset IIS does the change come through.

Is this an issue with Kestrel and IIS? is there some bug or something i missed here?

Note: WebAPI is published locally for testing + hosted via IIS on windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To request caching you should set `NoStore = true` inside the `ResponseCache` attribute class and remove the `Duration` attribute.
After you have set this attribute you will get this Headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

As mentioned in the comments it is a caching problem related to entityframework 6 and to avoid caching you should use `AsNoTracking()` just before the conversion type method, if you have one of course.

Comment: ahhh, i thought no store should only be on error pages, but yes ill give it a go. thanks

Comment: Headers are correct, but still zero change when i update the table data.

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: yes im using entity framework on the webapi, oh, you beleive the ORM is the culprit thats caching as default??

Comment: Ok, try to put `AsNoTracking()` at the end of the query just before the type conversion method (if you have one)

Comment: I will try, but wont this detatch the entities?

Comment: Ok NoTacking on the entities works.  This fixes the issue, but i am a little worried as to why i have to switch all this off, is there a reason you can think of that entity framework cant detect changes ?

Comment: Yes it seems to fix that issue but should we have too? shouldnt entity be able to detect change then act on iether passing data or providing a cached value?update you answer and ill throw a answered.

Comment: In EntityFramework 5 I've never got this issue (I use AsNoTracking just few times), I can only suppose that is something related to entityframework core

Comment: Update the question as request

Comment: May be useful: [Microsoft doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1)