# SignOutAsync Doesn't Sign Out

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

In my ASP.NET Core application I have this route to sign the user out:

```cs
        [HttpPost("logout")]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }
```

and I have this route to check the current username:

```cs
        [HttpGet("getusername")]
        public string GetUserName()
        {
            return _userManager.GetUserName(User);
        }
```

Yet, when the route is called, the second route continues to behave as if the user is logged in. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131517/asp-net-core-identity-2-0-signoutasync-is-not-logging-out-user-if-the-user-signe) claims that this can happen if the HTTP response that SignOutAsync produces doesn't get processed by the client, but it is requested via AJAX with this code:

```js
async function logout(){
    let response = await fetch('/api/user/logout', {method: 'post'});
    if(response.ok){
        Cookies.remove('username');
        window.location.reload();
    }else{
        alert(`Failed to log out due to networking error: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`)
    }
}
```

so the change is processed. Why does this code not behave as expected, where the sign out AJAX call ends the session? I'm using Firefox 81.0.1 on Linux as my client.

Comment: Can you debug the C# code? Is it actually getting called when you think it is? Is it throwing any exceptions? What does `_signInManager.SignOutAsync()` do?

Comment: @devNull I just confirmed via debugger that the method is called and that it does not throw any exceptions.

Comment: Is `window.location.reload();` occurring?

Comment: `Yet, when the route is called, the second route continues to behave as if the user is logged in.` Have you disabled caching for the second route?

Comment: @mjwills I just investigated caching of the second route, and it turns out that it was some unexpected UI in Firefox + some unexpected ASP.Net Core behavior. I'll give details in my self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. It depends on two unexpected facts about Asp.net Core and Firefox respectively:

- When a blank string is returned from an Asp.net Core route, it returns with HTTP 204 No Content.
- When Firefox receives a response of HTTP 204 No Content, it does not load the new page, but instead just shows the old page again (with a flash that suggests that an actual refresh is taking place!).

Taken together, when I signed out, the username sign-out occurred as it should on the backend, but I didn't realize it because when I refresh the username checking route in another tab, the username re-appeared. I consider this to be an issue with Firefox.

Comment: `but instead just shows the old page again (with a flash that suggests that an actual refresh is taking place!).` Have you disabled caching on the page? If not, it is valid for Firefox to render the old copy of the page.

Comment: @mjwills I haven't explicitly disabled caching, although the developer tools do not say that a cache is taking place, and I expect a refresh to disable caching (at least for the main page that I'm refreshing ).

Comment: Perhaps try disabling caching for the host page and the `GetUserName` endpoint.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the advice, but I'll leave it for now since I know how to deal with the issue and I have more important things to worry about than figuring out how to disable caching for a debugging route.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41692208/34092 - to be clear, if you aren't disabling caching for authenticated endpoints you will get these kinds of problems repeatedly. These are not "unexpected" issues.